# Just as crucially the order had come

Tags: adverbs

[Just as crucially] the order had come about only after the jammu and kashmir government had agreed to it and passed a similar legislation in its own assembly making it clear these powers were jammu and kashmir's to give and not india's to take.

What is the meaning of just as crucially in this context?

Comment: Jammu, Kashmir and India are all proper nouns and they should be spelled with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

A comma can be inserted after "crucially".

Crucially has its usual dictionary meaning: "very important"

Presumably, in the previous sentence, something else was discussed. The fact that "the order had come about after the Jammu and Kashmir government had agreed to it"  was *equally crucial* as the fact discussed in the previous sentence.

> My sister has green hair!  Just a strangely, my brother has a blue beard!

Two statements are made, the second is equally strange as the first.